# Where is the .xprofile for Elementary OS Luna

Tags: profile, elementary-os

I have this problem similar to this thread. https://askubuntu.com/questions/63863/unknown-monitor-intel-driver-want-to-set-vga-resolution-to-widescreen-tv/154818#154818 it fixed my resolution issue but it doesn't save when I logout. It says that I need to paste the cmd to .xprofile in the home folder. But in Elementary OS, I only say .profile ... when I vim it here is the contents:

```
 ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule in the Linux world if you find instructions telling you to "add X to file Y" and file Y does not exist, simply create it.

This is doubly true if the instructions are a bout a file in your `$HOME` folder whose name begins with a dot. Such files are usually configuration files where the user can add their own preferences for a particular service or program or whatever. These files often don't exist by default and are created by the user only when they want to overwrite the system-wide defaults.

In your case, just open your favorite text editor, write the lines you want to add to `.xprofile` there and save the file as `$HOME/.xprofile`.

And no, `.profile` and `.xprofile` are *not* the same thing.

Comment: i tried creating in my home$ and it's not working. `solidad@snet-old:/home$ ls -a
.  ..  solidad  .xprofile
solidad@snet-old:/home$ 
`

Comment: @MrA that should be your home directory (usually `/home/YourUser`, for example `/home/MrA`). Just run `echo $HOME` to see it.